# Auto index showing directories only

Tags: apache, .htaccess

If I add `Options +Indexes` in .htaccess this will display all files and subdirectories. However, I would like to exclude files for the current directory. i.e. display directories only for the current directory and display files and directories for any subdirectories.

Is this possible in .htaccess or will I need to write my own script to generate the directory index?

Comment: Maybe(!) it could be possible using [`IndexIgnore`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore) - if you block “all” files, only directories should be left.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll perhaps give that a try sometime. For now I decided as new subdirectories aren't created very often it was easier to just hard-code a index.html file for the main directory. If you wanted to try it and post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment of CBroe above, I've maked this approach tested in debian apache2 in .htaccess:

```
Options +Indexes
IndexIgnore *.*
```

This will ignore files with a file extension such as file.html. As we usually not name a directoty with a dot extension, so directories will be shown.

Please consult also apache autoindex reference http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html .

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Although this does not actually specifically identify files and directories, you are correct that in practice directories typically have no extension whereas files typically do. So it is a good workable solution provided we stick to these conventions. If no-one comes up with a better solution I'll accept this as the answer.